# How to migrate Confluent's Apache Kafka Schema Registry < 5.2.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I need to migrate Confluent Schema Registry 5.0.0.

Confluent's docs say that

> Starting with Confluent Platform 5.2.0, you can use Confluent
> Replicator to migrate schemas...

I wish there was a tool to do it also for the earlier versions. I cannot find any, and, therefore, I am considering writing a script to copy one schema registry to another using [Confluent's REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html).

However, before I start writing it, maybe someone knows a better solution, or an already existing script to do it?

Comment: There is no "out of the box" solution for Confluent Schemas Registry prior to 5.2.0 as Confluent Replicator.

There is also no way to control the assignment of schemas ids outside of a schema registry. Therefore, there is no possibility to create a script that would copy one schema registry into another persisting the same ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It seems that [Confluent's Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html) works also for the older versions of Confluent platform (if it is the source), so if you migrate to a newer (>= 5.2.0) version of Confluent platform from an old (< 5.2.0), you can simply use that.

Rest API won't work because you cannot set IDs of the schemas, so they will not be the same when you copy subjects.

As a matter of fact, by default, schemas are being written in a Kafka topic called `_schemas`. Therefore, the way to go is to copy the topic from a source to a destination Kafka cluster.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server http://[source] --topic _schemas --from-beginning --property print.key=true --timeout-ms 1000 1> schemas.log


bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list http://[destination] --topic _schemas --property parse.key=true < schemas.log
```